# pcntl_wait not interrupted by SIGTERM

Tags: php, sigterm, pcntl

According to the PHP docs for [pcntl_wait](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-wait.php),

> The wait function suspends execution of the current process until a child has exited, or until a signal is delivered whose action is to terminate the current process or to call a signal handling function.

However, when I run the following code and send SIGTERM to the parent process with `kill -s SIGTERM [pid]` the signal handler is only called *after* the child exits (i.e. I have to wait for the sleep to finish. Shouldn't `pcntl_wait()` be interrupted by SIGTERM?

fork_test.php:

```
<?php
  declare(ticks = 1);

  function sig_handler($signo) {
    switch ($signo) {
      case SIGTERM:
        echo 'SIGTERM' . PHP_EOL;
        break;
      default:
    }
  }

  pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, 'sig_handler');

  $pid = pcntl_fork();

  if ($pid == -1) {
     die('could not fork');
  }
  else if ($pid) {
    echo 'parent' . PHP_EOL;

    pcntl_wait($status);
  }
  else {
    echo 'child' . PHP_EOL;
    sleep(30);
  }
?>
```

Output (SIGTERM only appears after waiting 30 seconds):

```
$ php fork_test.php
child
parent
SIGTERM
```

**PHP Version => 5.3.3**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call to `pcntl_signal` specifies that the call should be restarted. Check the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php), `restart_syscalls` is `true` by default. So your call to `pcntl_signal` doesn't return until the child has terminated.

You have no call to [flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php). So PHP can hold the output of `echo` in a buffer.

So the behavior you are seeing is precisely the behavior you are requesting. The system call is restarted and the output is buffered.

Comment: Setting restart_syscalls to false did the trick, although I don't really understand what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Your `echo` is just writing to a buffer because you don't call `flush`. Since you had `restart_syscalls` set to true, the system call was restarted with the echo still sitting in the buffer.

Comment: Is flush also required in the CLI? (that's what I'm using)

Comment: It's required if you want the data flushed, otherwise it's fully buffered.

Comment: Some additional note on this. The pcntl_wait does not seem to be able to be interrupted by signal in PHP. You have to pass the restart_syscall to false in order to break from pcntl_wait.

The same is not true for sleep. Sleep will be interrupted no matter what the argument for restart_syscalls is and it won't get restarted.

Filesystem write will be interrupted and resumed (fortunately!) if the restart_syscalls is set to true however, if it is false, the syscall won't be resumed.

Answer (score 0):

`pcntl_wait` call cannot be interrupted by signals unless `restart_syscalls=false` OR a child dies.

From the documentation of `wait` syscall (which is what `pcntl_wait` calls) :

> ... they block until either a child changes
>        state or a **signal handler interrupts the call (assuming that system
>        calls are not automatically restarted** using the SA_RESTART flag of
>        sigaction(2)).

The last part is very important. The call will be interrupted only if the system calls are not automatically restarted (`restart_syscalls=false`).

Interestingly, not all syscall behave the same when a process receives a signal. For example, `sleep` syscall will either wait the amount of seconds OR wait for any signal before continuing. `sleep` won't be restarted where it was interupted even if you pass `restart_syscalls=true`. From the `sleep` manual :

> sleep() causes the calling thread to sleep either until the number of
>          real-time seconds specified in seconds have elapsed or **until a signal
>          arrives which is not ignored.**

**TL;DR; pcntl_wait cannot be interrupted unless you pass `restart_syscalls=false`.**