# PHP PCNTL - what does pcntl_signal()'s restart_syscalls parameter do?

Tags: php, signals, pcntl

I've been using PHP's [PCNTL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) for a little while now, but can't figure out what the `restart_syscalls` parameter of [`pcntl_signal()`](http://php.net/pcntl_signal) does. I tried looking around the Internets, but couldn't find any information. All the documentation says is:

> "Specifies whether system call restarting should be used when this signal arrives."

What is "system call restarting"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you programmed your signal handler to stop a process using signals like:

- **SIGTERM**: to terminate a process; it can be blocked, handled, and ignored unlike **SIGKILL**.
- **SIGKILL**: to immediately terminate a process
- **SIGSTOP**: to pause the process in its current state

[`restart_syscalls`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) *specifies whether system call restarting should be used when [`signo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) arrives*. Examples of `signo` are the three I listed above and there are much more.

This means, if `restart_syscalls` is set to the default value **TRUE**, this will restart certain system  calls after a process that was stopped by a signal `signo`. It restarts the interrupted system call with a time argument that is suitably adjusted to account for the time that has already elapsed.

I forward you to this very simple and clear example: [pcntl_wait not interrupted by SIGTERM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290366/pcntl-wait-not-interrupted-by-sigterm)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation & links! It's a bit clearer now, but honestly, I still don't quite understand what "system call restarting" is... :( In fact, I don't understand the whole notion of why a system call would have to be restarted, or what restarting a system call even means/implies.