# doubts about pcntl_signal in php

Tags: php, pcntl

How to understand the third parameter `restart_syscalls`  in `pcntl_signal` ?
the default value is `true`
when it needs to be set to `false` ?

Comment: I guess looking at the documentation might help

Comment: Regarding how he asked, can not you see that he already checked the documentation? @Breeze

Comment: Does [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878380/php-pcntl-what-does-pcntl-signals-restart-syscalls-parameter-do/36735303#36735303) help you or not?

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ no, knowing the name and default of a parameter doesn't tell me he looked at the documentation. Every good IDE tells you.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ  thank you very much , help me a lot

Comment: @Breeze I may not be clear expression ， I already check the  documentation first